# Mono c# vs c++ in opengl game development?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, mono, language-comparisons

Which of these languages is better for opengl game with primary platform linux?
I would like if you compared them in performance and libraries support.

Comment: this may be better asked on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: yes, i mean mono C#, i've edit this

Comment: I would steer clear of 3rd party libraries such as mono.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ is a low-level, highly flexible and powerful language. It compiles native code (it's fast) and has a large array of helpful libraries. I would recommend it for any OpenGL project. You may also look into other c-family languages, that share many of the same benefits.

(I sound like an ad)

Comment: Yes, i know that c++ is faster, but c# have nicer syntax. C# has GC, which can make developent easier, but app slower. Is there big performance differences in these two languages?

Comment: Last I heard, the vast majority of games were written in C++. There is a price to pay for nice syntax. :)

Comment: The advantages of C# is really not that big; modern C++ and careful design will bring GC into your program, without (most of) the performance hit. Syntax wise, that's that's up to you. I personally prefer the syntax of C++, but do like some of the features that have been added in C#. Most of the important ones, like externally readable/internally writable variables, can be had with a bit of template magic -- generally, people don't use templates enough and that's one of the reasons people think languages like Java and C# have better syntax (IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know enough about C++ and C# to answer this question yourself then I suggest you go for C#.

In C++ you may get slightly better performance, but only if you have enough experience with it. Otherwise it'll probably end up being slower.

C++ libraries can be easily called from Mono using pInvoke, but Mono libraries cannot be used from C++ (without embedding entire mono in your game).

Answer (score 1):

Library support is about the same, all of the 3d rendering libraries I can think of have .net bindings.  If you want lower level libraries(openGL, openAL etc.) OpenTk has bindings for just about everything you need. A quick look at the programming language shootout looks like mono is 1/2 the speed of G++ I would be really surprised if that held in the general case though.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it largely depend on the code to be developed, I mean, the rest of the app. For pro gaming stuff and so on C++ seems to be the stronger choice.

I've used OpenGL + C# to render our version tree (plastic scm) on Linux, Windows, Mac with very good results, but we're not doing a game! :)